# Creating and Dragging Div within Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

so far i have a container div that holds a button and when the button is click it creates a div with a set id="newcard" which is resizable (this part works 'correctly'). However, when i incorporate dragging the div element simply does not drag.  Any help?

```js
$(function(){

 $(".createcard").click(function() {
  var domElement = $('<div id="newcard" ></div>');
  $('.notecard-container').append(domElement);

 });
 $('#newcard').draggable();

});
```

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.createcard {
 bottom: 5%;
 left: 5%;
 width: 125px;
 height: 45px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid transparent; 
 
 outline: none;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;

 -webkit-transition:  .4s ease;
 -moz-transition:  .4s ease;
 -o-transition:  .4s ease;
 -ms-transition:  .4s ease;
 transition:  .4s ease;
 transition: .4.0s
}

.createcard:hover {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; 
 
 -webkit-transition:  .4s ease;
 -moz-transition:  .4s ease;
 -o-transition:  .4s ease;
 -ms-transition: .4s ease;
 transition:  .4s ease;
 transition: .4.0s
}

#newcard{
 position: absolute;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 min-width:150px;
 min-height:150px;
 max-width:300px;
 max-height:300px;
 top:10%;
 left:10%;
 background: white;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.notecard-container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 7%;
 left: 2%;
 right: 2%;
 bottom: 2%;
 background: rgb(255, 228, 181);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="aos.css">
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Post-it note</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="notecard-container">
   <button class="createcard" id="createcard">New    Card</button>

  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Input JavaScript and jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your second statement inside the function is outside scope of the inner function that's why the element is not becoming draggable in your script.

Comment: it is within the main function? the id, 'newcard' is referring to all newcard elements.

Comment: Yeah it is.
`$(function(){

 $(".createcard").click(function() {
  var domElement = $('<div id="newcard" ></div>');
  $('.notecard-container').append(domElement);
   $('#newcard').draggable();

 });
});`

Comment: huh it worked. thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `draggable()` call into the click handler:

```
$(function(){

    $(".createcard").click(function() {
        var domElement = $('<div id="newcard" ></div>');
        $('.notecard-container').append(domElement);
        $('#newcard').draggable();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `draggable()` after creating the element.

Here is a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/dk341jjv/1/